# Using android download manager phonegap 3.0

Tags: cordova

I am using Cordova/Phonegap to write a small program which basically downloads a file from the server and places in the local sd-card. This app for now will only run on Android. I have this function which uses fileTransfer from cordova libraries which downloads the required file from the server.

```
this.downloadFile=function(){
        var filePath = '';
        var remoteFile = config.url + 'api_download';
        var localFileName = this.constants.currentFileName;
        window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, function(fileSystem) {
            fileSystem.root.getFile(localFileName, {create: true, exclusive: false}, function(fileEntry) {
                var localPath = fileEntry.fullPath;
                var fullPath =  fileEntry.fullPath
                var metadata = fileEntry.getMetadata();
                if (device.platform === "Android" && localPath.indexOf("file://") === 0) {
                    localPath = localPath.substring(7);
                }                 
                filePath = localPath;
                var ft = new FileTransfer();
                ft.download(remoteFile,
                    localPath, function(entry) {
                        // Now file is downloaded, we need the mimetype
                        var type = returnMimeType(fullPath);
                        if(type != ''){
                            CDV.WEBINTENT.startActivity({
                                    action: CDV.WEBINTENT.ACTION_VIEW,
                                    url: fullPath,
                                    type: type},
                                function() {},
                                function() {console.log('Failed to open URL via Android Intent');}
                            );
                            console.log("Local Path is :"); console.log(fullPath);
                        }
                    }, fail);
            }, fail);
        }, fail);
    }
```

This is fine and works exactly as expected, but the user doesn't know if the file is downloading or not. I have no way to notify this and so I was wondering if I could use the Android's default download manager instead of the this method. Or Could I somehow show the progress of the download, it will solve the probelm as well.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with downloading xml files. Solved it with this simple script: [Spin.js](http://fgnass.github.io/spin.js/) When downloading start, blur screen and start spinner, at the end stop spinner :)

Comment: Oh well, this project is all over now. But thanks for the suggestion! :D

Answer (score 0):

use this plugin to access android DownloadManager

https://github.com/sgrebnov/cordova-plugin-background-download

i use it in my cordova app and it work fine.